# Differences in browser scope treatment of chrome/firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, cross-browser, scope

This alerts x in chrome, but not on firefox (Chrome 25.0/FF 11.0):

```
var x="hi.", b;
(b = document.createElement("button")).innerHTML = "click me";
b.setAttribute("onclick", "alert(x)"); // Doesn't work on FF, but works on Chrome
document.body.appendChild(b);
```

It works on both when I use DOM (b.onclick, like the code below), but returns a "x not defined" error when using the attribute in string form, like in the code above.

```
var x="hi.", b;
(b = document.createElement("button")).innerHTML = "click me";
b.onclick = function(){alert(x)}; // Works on FF/Chrome
document.body.appendChild(b);
```

What are the differences between the two browsers that cause this?

Answer (score 1):

This should work in FF and Chrome, but not in IE, you need to actually pass the variable ?

```
var x="hi.", b;
(b = document.createElement("button")).innerHTML = "click me";
b.setAttribute("onclick", "alert('"+x+"')");
document.body.appendChild(b);
```

In (older versions of) IE you can't set inline javascript with setAttribute as far as I know.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/zZtVt/) (tested in FF 19 and newest Chrome)

Comment: @Teemu - Uhm, you still need to pass the variable, if it works in Chrome like it is, it must be because `x` is somehow global or some other fluke? And when I try the OP's code in Chrome, I get "x is not defined" in the console.

Comment: Well, my FF, IE9 & 10, Chrome and Opera all alerted "hi." when running the fiddle of yours...

Comment: @Teemu - how nice. I just seemed to remember to you could'nt set inline events like onclick with setAttribute in IE, but if it works, I guess you can, at least in the newer versions.

Comment: @Teemu - I actually need to pass the variable because it changes during execution.

Comment: @Macmod Did you notice a little difference between the codes? You have `b.setAttribute("onclick", "alert(x)");` and adeneo has `b.setAttribute("onclick", "alert('"+x+"')");`, which will fix the problem in all (modern) browsers.

Comment: @Macmod - If you really want it to be global, you can always explicitly set it to the window object (global), like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/zZtVt/2/). I tested this in Chrome and FF as well, and it works just fine.

Comment: @adeneo It works just fine. Thanks. The question of why this happens is yet to be answered, anyway.

Comment: It happens because you're passing x as a string in the alert function. That means x has to be defined in the same scope as the element you attach the onclick handler to, which it obviously is'nt. Your code does'nt work for me in either browser, so somehow Chrome must have picked up the x variable somewhere else in your code or something similar and made it global, it's the only reason why it would be defined in that scope.

Comment: @adeneo Of course x has to be defined in the same scope. The question is why Chrome "picks up" the x variable (or puts it naturally when declared) "somewhere else" and Firefox doesn't

Comment: What I wanna know is why Chrome treats scopes differently than Firefox (and exactly what is this technical difference)